# how to remove redundancy of the words from the list in each row python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
29                             TECH IS A  BLOODBATH.
219       ONLY 3 THINGS GUARANTEED IN LIFE, DEATH, TAXES...
255       *ATH MARKET IS AT ATH IN ZOMBIE ECONOMY*\n\n*MARKE...
276       MY APPLE WATCH REMINDING ME TO BREATHE WHILE I...
314                           NEW AMC MEGATHREAD AMC WHEN??????
```

My list

```
['SRNE', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'ATH', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE']
```

I for each row I want to remove words that are redundant from the list
I was thinking about this command but I don't know how to interpret it

```
def foo(row):
    set_of_tickers = set()
    # find if tickers in row.text for each ticker
    # if constains -> add to set
    return set_of_tickers

a = df_ticker.apply(foo)
```

where ticker is a list of strings, text is the column with text in each row
output that I need

```
29                             TECH IS A  BLOODBATH.
219       ONLY 3 THINGS GUARANTEED IN LIFE, DEATH, TAXES...
255       *ATH MARKET IS AT IN ZOMBIE ECONOMY*\n\n*MARKE...
276       MY APPLE WATCH REMINDING ME TO BREATHE WHILE I...
314                           NEW AMC MEGATHREAD WHEN?????
```

as you can see lines 255 and 314 have only one word from the list
thank you for help

Comment: Can you post some sample data of input and required output ?

Comment: Define what you mean by redundant (perhaps duplicate?)

Comment: yeah dublicate .

Comment: I have added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little function that does the job, you can apply it to the df column of interest.

```
def dedup(sentence, to_dedup):
    for word in to_dedup:
        while sentence.split().count(word) > 1:
            sentence = ''.join(sentence.rsplit(word, 1)).replace('  ', ' ')
    return sentence


sentence = 'NEW AMC MEGATHREAD AMC WHEN??????'
to_dedup = ['SRNE', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'ATH', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE']

dedup_sentence = dedup(sentence, to_dedup)
print(dedup_sentence)
#NEW AMC MEGATHREAD WHEN??????
```

The code is quite self-explanatory. The only "unusual" part is `''.join(sentence.rsplit(word, 1)).replace('  ', ' ')` which splits the sentence from the right side once (In your example you keep the first occurrence, the most left one) using `word` as the split key. Finally, it replaces double spaces with single ones.

In you case you can try:

```
def f(row):
    sentence = row['text']
    to_dedup = ['SRNE', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'ATH', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE']
    return dedup(sentence, to_dedup) #this is the function defined before

df['text'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: how would i apply to the column. I am sorry im new to python

Comment: What is the column's name? I will make an example ad hoc

Comment: the column name is text

Comment: @yanbiceps try it out, it should work, else please share your DataFrame so I can work with the same data you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['TECH IS A  BLOODBATH.',
                   'ONLY 3 THINGS GUARANTEED IN LIFE, DEATH, TAXES...',
                  '*ATH MARKET IS AT ATH IN ZOMBIE ECONOMY*\n\n*MARKE...',
                  'MY APPLE WATCH REMINDING ME TO BREATHE WHILE I...',
                  'NEW AMC MEGATHREAD AMC WHEN??????'])


lst=['SRNE', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'ATH', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE']
cnt=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    cnt = 0
    for k in range(len(lst)):
        cnt=(df[0][i].count(lst[k]))
        if cnt >= 2:
            s=df[0][i]
            index = s.rfind(lst[k])
            lenh=len(lst[k])+index
            s=s[0: index:] + s[lenh + 1::]
            df[0][i]=s
print(df[0])
```